# android registering contextmenu for an option menu item

Tags: android

I want on an option menu item click a context menu should come.
Is it possible to register a context menu for an option menu item?
If it possible then how?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Just read documentation about [menus](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/menus.html) in android:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:id="@+id/item1"
          android:icon="@drawable/item1"
          android:title="@string/item1" />
    <!-- menu group -->
    <group android:id="@+id/group1">
        <item android:id="@+id/groupItem1"
              android:title="@string/groupItem1" />
        <item android:id="@+id/groupItem2"
              android:title="@string/groupItem2" />
    </group>
</menu>
```

Comment: If u have any sample example plz give me.

Comment: This one above is not enough?

Answer (score 0):

check this;

http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/menus.html

http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/menu-resource.html